# fetch request return empty array

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

When using client.fetch to get the data from sanity I'm getting an empty array altough when I'm test the query on the vesion tool I'm getting the curret resualts.

this is the code I'm using

```
import { groq } from "next-sanity";
import { client } from "@/lib/sanity.client";
const query = groq`
        *[_type=='product'] {
        ...,
        categories[]->
        }`
const plans = await client.fetch( query );
```

it suppose to return array of size 2 but it returning an empty array.